# How to get the type of a generic class in java?

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection, gson

```
public class Network_Generic {

public static <T> void get_generic(String url, final VolleyCallback volleyCallback,T t)
{
    Network_GetString.get_String(url,new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {

                String json=(String)o;
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType();

                T jsonBean = gson.fromJson(json, type);
                volleyCallback.onSuccess(jsonBean);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String error) {

            volleyCallback.onFailure(error);

        }
    });
}
public class Network_Location {
  public static void get_locations(final Integer id,final VolleyCallback volleyCallback)
{
    String url="/location/view/"+id.toString()+".json";
    Network_Generic.get_generic(url,new VolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    Json_Location_Bean json_location_bean=(Json_Location_Bean)o;
                    volleyCallback.onSuccess(json_location_bean);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String error) {
                    volleyCallback.onFailure(error);

                }
            },new Json_Location_Bean()

    );

}
```

Here I would like to get the type of "T" in method get_String,but failed. 
The compiler told me that "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to Json_Location_Bean. 
Could someone help me to get the type of T? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
t.getClass().getName()
```

Comment: You mean where to modify your code?  I don't know, you haven't said what you want to do with the class name.